# How to access the list inside dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I have dict structure as shown in image.I am want to access wavelength list values of it.
[image: dictionary]

How to access it or store the wavelength list in another variable.

Comment: There is *nothing special* about the value being a list. You access the list same way you access any other value in a dictionary: by using the key.

Comment: My mind meld does not visualize the code properly, please provide it explicitly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should simply be:

dict['wavelength']

Where "dict" is your dictionary name; which looks like it's "n2" maybe.  The returned value will be the list that you're looking for.